# Save ggplot to stdout

Tags: r, ggplot2, stdout

Is it possible to save a ggplot figure to stdout, preferably with `ggsave`? How can I do this?

I am looking to do something like:

```
Rscript make_fig.R > my_fig.png
```

Answer (score 0):

On Unix systems, it's posisble to use the device files:

```
ggsave(plot = p, filename = "/dev/stdout", device = "png")
```